# Terraform Use Map for a for_each statement

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I have an issue, and need a bit of help.  My knowledge of Terraform isn't all that great, and I need some advice on how to make this happen.  I have a map variable with the following information in it:

In variables.tf:

```
variable "users" {
  type = "map"
}
```

in the Terraform.tfvars:

```
users = {
  "user1" = {

  },

  "user2" = {
   instance = ["instance_size"]
  },

  "user3" = {
    bucket = ["bucket1"]
  },

  "user4" = {
    bucket = ["bucket1", "bucket2"]
  },

  "user5" = {
    instance = ["instance_size"]
    bucket = ["bucket1", "bucket2", "bucket3"]
  }
```

And what I want to do is to take the bucket information out of that variable and apply a AWS policy kinda like so:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sm_s3_bucket" {
  for_each = var.users
    statement {
      actions = [
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject",
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ]
      resources = formatlist("arn:aws:s3:::%s", each.value.bucket)
    }
}
```

How do I go about getting only the bucket info for each user out of the variable and into the resource command?  Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with your current results versus your expected results.

Comment: What "resource command"? Your question is incomplete and lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to create a policy document for users who have `bucket` specified, it could be done for example like this:

```
for_each = {
  for user, attr in var.users : user => attr if contains(keys(attr), "bucket")
}
```